# How to write scripts to keep punctuation in Stanford dependency parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-processing

In order to get some specific dependency information I write a java script to parse sentences rather than directly use ParserDemo.java that Stanford Parser 3.9.1 provided. But I found punctuation is missing after got typedDependencies. Is there any function to get punctuation in Stanford Parser?
**I had to write a script to parse sentences myself for the reason that I need to create a SemanticGraph from a List of TypedDependencies, in order to use methods in SemanticGraph to get evey single tokens dependent information(include punctuation).**

```
public class ChineseFileTest3 {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String modelpath = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/xinhuaFactored.ser.gz";
    LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(modelpath);
    String textFile = "data/chinese-onesent-unseg-utf8.txt";
    demoDP(lp,textFile);

}
public static void demoDP(LexicalizedParser lp, String filename){

for(List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(filename)) {

    Tree t = lp.apply(sentence);

    ChineseGrammaticalStructure gs = new ChineseGrammaticalStructure(t);
    Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
    System.out.println(tdl);

}
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep punctuation in Stanford dependency parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130722/how-to-keep-punctuation-in-stanford-dependency-parser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using the parser standalone but instead just running a pipeline.  That will maintain the punctuation.

There is comprehensive documentation about using the Java API for pipelines here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

You need to set the properties for Chinese.  A quick way to do that is with this line of code

```
Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
```